# Executing sp_send_dbmail with an Agent Job: Failed to initialize sqlcmd library

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sp-send-dbmail

I'm executing a SP that dynamically builds a global temp table of data gathered from multiple databases. At the end of this SP is this line of code:

```
Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = @dbmailProfileName,
    @recipients = @emailRecipents,
    @subject = @subject,
    @body = @body,
    @query = 'Select * From tempdb..##MyTempTable'
```

This SP works perfectly when I execute it manually, however, when I let my Server Agent Job run it, it fails with the following error:

```
Message
Executed as user: WORKGROUP\MyServer2016$. Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050)  Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).  The step failed.
```

Commenting out `@query` portion of the SP will work fine, but that's useless since I need the data emailed.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying the column names in the `Select` statement?

Comment: Previously I had not, that wouldn't be acceptable since the data generated is dynamic. It's iterating through a list of queries, all with different select parameters and sending an email per query.

Since I'm curious if that is the issue, I inserted the select columns and had it run for one of my queries. It did not fix the issue, same error was present.

Answer (score 1):

I knew it was some kind of security issue, but my lack of DBA skills defeated me here. However, I found a workaround solution which worked, not exactly what I was looking for, but it works.

Editing the Job Step to include an Execute As with my working login:

```
Execute As Login='MyUser'
GO
exec DBNAME.dbo.SPNAME
GO
Revert
GO
```

Since `MyUser` could run this thing manually, I executed as my login.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error then, after numerous trial and error attempts, another error popped up:

```
  The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_sysmail_format_query',
  database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.
```

I added the user to the public role in the master database then added this permission for the user:

```
  grant execute on xp_sysmail_format_query to [myuser]
```

It seems that Database Mail relies on this stored proc.  After doing this, the email job works fine.  Note:  I run the job as a designated user.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try use the @execute_query_database parameter? If that doesn't work, try to add the Sql Server Agent account to the Sql Server as a sysadmin

Comment: I've tried setting this parameter to the database name my SP resides in, and also tried setting it to tempdb since I'm querying a global temp table, but neither worked. Same error.

I've also already set the NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT user to sysadmin. This user also owns the database and tempdb with permission db_owner.

Comment: In your error is said that your query is executed as WORKGROUP\MyServer2016$

Comment: You know that always confused me, that isn't even a user. Should I just create a user called that?

Comment: MyServer2016 is the server name/domain name

Comment: I'm not a expert in this area, but i think it's some of built-in Windows service accounts. To change a user which is executed in your job, select another user in job step properties (selection list titled "run as").