# How to send json query as attachment using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sp-send-dbmail

Is it possible to export the data from a column into json and email?

**Col is NVARCHAR(MAX) storing entire json string.**

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
  @profile_name = 'Profile',
  @recipients = 'a@b.com',
  @subject = @Subject,
  @body = @Body,  
  @query = 'SELECT TOP(1) [col] FROM [dbo].[tbl] ORDER BY [Date] DESC;',
  @execute_query_database = 'DBName',
  @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
  @query_attachment_filename = 'Report.json';
```

Executing produces error:

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147417850.

Comment: If you're on a (fully supported) version of SQL Server, you could use `FOR JSON`. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @Larnu. The entire json is already within a single column, so I don't need to build the json. I just need the string in that column adding into an attachment with json extension.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. Seems like you're missing the required permissions ([Executing sp_send_dbmail with an Agent Job: Failed to initialize sqlcmd library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494500/executing-sp-send-dbmail-with-an-agent-job-failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library)). And the @recipients parameter.

Comment: I actually have recipients, I just missed them from my questions code. I also have permission to execute the query manually and user has db mail perms.